# Limit number of json results - Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rails-api

I am creating Rails API and when I do get request to `mywebsite.com/posts/all` it shows me all the post data. I am trying to do `mywebsite.com/posts/all?limit=20` to show 20 results or some other number. What is the way to achieve it with rails?

Comment: google it........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit will not work, each time if u call this method it will return only last 20 records, 
Best way to achieve this result using pagination, here you can limit number record passing when each request is hitting

You can use **gem will_paginate**

In controller

```
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

In the view

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

For  info about will_paginate
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/README.md

If u r using API pass params ass below

```
GET /v1/posts?page=1&per_page=10
```

Change value in controller

```
@posts = Post.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: params[:per_page])
```

Comment: Does will_paginate work if I am doing API since I don't have views and using it for building mobile app.

Comment: Pass params as above it will work like charm, if u want second list /v1/posts?page=2&per_page=10  son on...

Answer (score 1):

Easy way for this is

```
@posts = Post.limit(params[:limit])
```

But you could also use [will_paginate gem](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)

Comment: The `will_paginate` gem lets you easily handle the subsequent pages nicely. But, yes, you could easily roll your own if you wanted to.